# Increase the heigth of an image inside multiple select dropdown - CSS

Tags: html, css

I've an image inside all the text fields and drop down similar to this

[image]

[image]

But for multiple select drop down box what I get is something like this

[image]

I want the image to be displayed like this for multiple select drop down

[image]

Tried `heigth: 100%` in the css but it doesn't work.

The CSS I have for this is

```
    .symbol{
    background: #FFFFFF url(../images/symbol.gif) no-repeat 4px 4px;
    background-position: left;
    }
```

What change should I make in CSS to get that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one..

```
.symbol{
    background: #FFFFFF url(../images/symbol.gif) repeat-y 4px 4px;
    background-position: left;
    }
```

and learn about the repeat-x and repeat-y property that is very helpful in these condition..  [HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_background-repeat.htm)  is the best one with online practice.. happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
background-size: 2px 100%;
```

Comment: I would also recommend using BASE64 background image for these kind of small images. Using a tool like: http://i-tools.org/base64